# Confused about error when creating a table with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, string-constant

I'm working through a tutorial on data-driven astronomy on Coursera, and one of the activities is to create a table populated with exoplanets. My script is:

```
create table Planet (
    kepler_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    koi_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    kepler_name VARCHAR(15),
    status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    radius FLOAT NOT NULL
    );

insert into Planet (kepler_id, koi_name, kepler_name, status, radius)
values (6862328, "K00865.01", NULL, "CANDIDATE", 119.021),
(10187017, "K00082.05", "Kepler-102 b", "CONFIRMED", 5.286),
(10187017, "K00082.04", "Kepler-102 c", "CONFIRMED", 7.071);
select * from Planet;
```

The table is created without errors, but I get

```
psql:query.sql:12: ERROR:  column "K00865.01" does not exist
LINE 2: values (6862328, "K00865.01", NULL, "CANDIDATE", 119.021),
                         ^
```

when trying to populate the table. I'm confused about why it's complaining that there's no *column* called "K00865.01", when it should be a data value.

Comment: And I'm confused as to why you are using double quotes for what you intend to be a string value.

Comment: You're using double quotes instead of single quotes

Comment: String constants need to be [enclosed in single quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) in SQL

Comment: Thank you, all. I'm an import from Python, so I didn't know this.